# Is it ok to catch and reraise an exception inside Django transaction.atomic()?

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-orm

Django's docs say this about `transaction.atomic()` and exceptions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

> Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!
>
> When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll back. If you catch and handle exceptions inside an atomic block, you may hide from Django the fact that a problem has happened. This can result in unexpected behavior.
>
> This is mostly a concern for DatabaseError and its subclasses such as IntegrityError. After such an error, the transaction is broken and Django will perform a rollback at the end of the atomic block. If you attempt to run database queries before the rollback happens, Django will raise a TransactionManagementError. You may also encounter this behavior when an ORM-related signal handler raises an exception.
>
> The correct way to catch database errors is around an atomic block as shown above. If necessary, add an extra atomic block for this purpose. This pattern has another advantage: it delimits explicitly which operations will be rolled back if an exception occurs.
>
> If you catch exceptions raised by raw SQL queries, Django’s behavior is unspecified and database-dependent.

Is it okay to do this or does this cause "unexpected behavior"?

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # something
    try:
        # something
    except:
        logger.exception("Report error here.")
        raise
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the docs, I would ensure that the correct Exception gets re-raised, others errors you might handle independently. For django it is only necessary that it gets notified regarding things that went wrong when talking to the database.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # something
    try:
        # something
    except DatabaseError as db_err:
        logger.exception("Report error here.")
        raise db_err
    except Exception:
        # do something else
        # no need to reraise
        # as long as you handle it properly and db integrity is guaranteed
```

Comment: But then they make vague threats like "This is mostly a concern for DatabaseError and its subclasses...".  Mostly?  What do I do with MOSTLY?

Comment: I agree - on the other hand this topic is far away from simple and I understand that the developers are careful in what they write down. I've tried to read [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py#L107), but without deep understanding of `django.db` this is not easy to answer. The comment above the class is quite useful. You might want to dig deeper in a debug session or wait for someone who __knows__ already.

Answer (score 6):

This example will clear your doubt.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    try:
        # if you do something that raises ONLY db error. ie. Integrity error
    except Exception:
        # and you catch that integrity error or any DB error like this here.
        # now if you try to update your DB
        model = Model.objects.get(id=1)
        model.description = "new description"
        model.save()
        # This will be illegal to do and Django in this case 
        # will raise TransactionManagementError suggesting 
        # you cannot execute any queries until the end of atomic block.
```

Now in case you are raising your custom exception like this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    try:
        # raising custom exception
        raise Exception("some custom exception")
    except Exception:
        # and you catch that exception here
        # now if you try to update your DB
        model = Model.objects.get(id=1)
        model.description = "new description"
        model.save()
        # Django will allow you to update the DB.
```

Comment: Super helpful explanation, thanks! Much better than the docs.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it okay to do this or does this cause "unexpected behavior"?

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # something
    try:
        # something
    except:
        logger.exception("Report error here.")
        raise
```

Except for the bare except clause (you want at least `except Exception:`), this is ok,  assuming your logger doesn't touch the database (which would be a very bad idea anyway) and the logger call doesn't raise another exception (in which case I have no idea what will actually happen).

But you'd get the same result inverting the `transaction.atomic()` block and the `try/except`, ie:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        # something
        # something
except Exception:
    logger.exception("Report error here.")
    raise
```

Comment: hey long shot. Any idea when conducting unit test, how do i test except block in a situation like this?

Comment: @IbrahimNoor I use `with self.assertRaises(MyCustomError) as e:` inside my tests ( inheriting from `TestCase` of `django.test` ) and call the function I expect to raise the exception inside it. Then outside `with` I can access `e.exception.error` and compare it to the message I expect my exception to raise.

Comment: What does `raise` mean? What if you need to return a Response object?